# Any connection between "escheat" and "cheat"?

Tags: etymology

According to Google, "Escheat is a common law doctrine which transfers the property of a person who dies without heirs to the crown or state. It serves to ensure that property is not left in "limbo" without recognized ownership."

I'm wondering if it has any etymological relationship to the word "cheat", as in to swindle someone.

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary is [where relevant] one of the reference works one should check before asking a question on ELU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *escheat* is used only in formal legal parlance, and goes back to old feudal law, It basically means *to confiscate*. Its etymology per the OED is:

> Etymology:  Middle English eschete, < Old French eschete, eschaete,
>   escheoite, noun of action (originally feminine past participle), < Old
>   French escheoir (modern French échoir) < late Latin *excadēre
>   (classical Latin excidĕre) to fall to a person's share, < Latin ex out
>   + cadĕre (vulgar Latin cadēre, Old French cheoir) to fall. In continental Old French the noun meant succession, inheritance, esp.
>   collateral inheritance; in England the etymological sense received a
>   different application. As in many other words (compare exchange) the
>   prefix es- was in the 16–17th cent. often replaced by ex- after Latin
>   analogies.(Show Less)

**The meaning given** is:

> a. trans. To make an escheat of, confiscate; to hand over as an
>   escheat to or into. (Some apparent examples of the pass. may belong to
>   the intr. sense  2.)
>
> 1687   N. Johnston Assurance Abby & Church-lands 40   It was the
>   Opinion of the Justices that they were Escheated to the Lords of the
>   Fee.
>
> 1855   H. H. Milman Hist. Lat. Christianity IV. ix. v. 87
>   He..escheated their estates into the hands of laymen.
>
> 1873   W. H. Dixon Hist. Two Queens vi. ix,   His honours lost, his
>   lands escheated, and his liberty restrained.

***Cheat*** comes from the same root, but in modern parlance has come to mean *defraud by deceit*.